# Need to generate sequence Number of my choice in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, identity, row-number

I have a requirement.

There are three tables, some where later data needs be merged and should be given to user for auditing purposes.

Is there a way to generate a sequence number unique to each table, so that sequence numbers don't get overlapped.

For example :
table A can contain numbers from 1 to 100000
table B can contain numbers from 200000 to 300000
table C should contain numbers from 300000 to 400000

I think this can be done with identity columns options like start value and max value.
If i choose identity, generated sequence wont be in my control, it will be randomly chosen by Oracle.

Is there any way this can be done easily with row_number function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row_number() function directly, to generate numbers from 1:

```
row_number() Over(Order by field_name)
```

If you want to customize where to start the count from, you can add it to the row numbers. For example, if you want to start from 1001:

```
1000 + row_number() Over(Order by field_name)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps as of now.

Comment: Slightly more efficient might be to just use ROWNUM if you don't need to group.
ROWNUM + 1000 as MY_CUSTOM_ID, no sorting required (unless you need to sort)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way this can be done easily with row_number function ?

Not really, if you want these sequences to be populated as you `INSERT` data into these tables.

> Is there a way to generate a sequence number unique to each table, so that sequence numbers don't get overlapped.

If you want unique ids across multiple tables, you have a few options (from easy to less easy).

1. Use a single Oracle sequence for all of the tables.  The numbers used by each table won't be nice ranges (e.g., 1-100000 for table #1, etc).  However, the same number will never be used in more than one table, ensuring that you will be able to merge them later on no problem.
2. Define multiple Oracle sequences, one for each table.  Define each sequence with a `START WITH`, `MINVALUE`, and `MAXVALUE` to define its range.
3. Use a single Oracle sequence with a `MAXVALUE`.  If the maximum value is 999999, for example, insert into table #1 with `my_sequence.nextval`, table #2 with `1000000+my_sequence.nextval`, and table #3 with `2000000+my_sequence.nextval`.

Option #2 can be used if you want to use identity columns instead of sequences.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for providing lot of options, will use any one of these. Appreciate your help.